# Why does the break command not exit the loop?

Tags: python

In the code below, I have defined 3 threads running for certain intervals. The code is correct. When the break command is reached, I want the code to find the entered number and stop, but it does not stop and continues. Why is that?

```
import threading
import time    

def thread_func_1():
    
    for i in range(1000,3334):
        time.sleep(0.02)
        print(f"thred1 {i}")
        if number == i:
            print(f"1.. Thread şifreyi buldu: {i}")
            break
            

def thread_func_2():
    
    for i in range(3334,6667):
        time.sleep(0.02)
        print(f"thred2 {i}")
        
        if number == i:
            print(f"2. Thread şifreyi buldu: {i}")
            break

def thread_func_3():
    
    for i in range(6667,10000):
        time.sleep(0.02)
        print(f"thred3 {i}")
        
        if number == i:
            print(f"3. Thread şifreyi buldu: {i}")
            break


print("Lütfen bir sayı giriniz: ")
number = int(input())

t1 = threading.Thread(target=thread_func_1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=thread_func_2)
t3 = threading.Thread(target=thread_func_3)

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
```

Comment: ı didnt understand. Can you give more details to me please

Comment: how can ı fixed this code

Comment: What number are you inputting?

Comment: For example, I enter the number 1250. Then if number == i, I want to write the contents of print("..") and I want the program to stop, but it does not stop, it continues counting from 1251.

Comment: All threads will terminate for one of 2 reasons. 1) Either the *for* loop is exhausted 2) the loop value matches the input. They will however run for a long time due to the *sleep()*. Maybe you're just being impatient. Maybe you want all threads to stop once you've found a match. You'll need some kind of *sentinel* for that

Comment: @IkramKhanNiazi Why does *number* need to be passed to the threads when it's available globally? It would be better style to do so but isn't actually necessary in this case

Comment: ohh no. I think I understood. When 1250 is written, the relevant function already stops. But other functions are still searching because they are threaded. I understand. So how can I do this? After the number is found, I want other threads to stop running.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you provided, the `break` statement inside each of the threads only breaks out of the loop inside that thread. It does not stop the other threads or the entire program.

To stop all of the threads when the number is found, you can use a shared flag variable that is checked by all of the threads. When the number is found, the flag can be set to `True`, and the threads can check the flag and exit if it is True.

Example:

```py
# Create a flag variable to signal when the number has been found
found = False

def thread_func_1():
    # Allow found to be overridden inside the function
    global found
    for i in range(1000,3334):
        # Check the flag and exit if it is True
        if found:
            break
        time.sleep(0.02)
        print(f"thred1 {i}")
        if number == i:
            print(f"1.. Thread şifreyi buldu: {i}")
            # Set the flag to True
            found = True
```

Variables that are created outside of a function are global variables. Normally, when you create a variable inside a function, that variable is local, and can only be used inside that function. Therefore, you have to use the `global` keyword if you want to change a global variable inside a function.

Comment: Should I define it this way for each function?

Comment: @Fatih yes, each function should be defined the same way.

Comment: thank you very much but there is only one problem "Thread 2 found password:" after printing other 2 more times working. Can we prevent this too?

Comment: It is susceptible to race conditions, and since you have 3 threads running, it is not unlikely that the other 2 threads would print their numbers before stopping. But you should get a maximum of 2 extra numbers, one from each thread.

Comment: Yes, I'm just getting the two numbers from 2 different threads. So it's about race conditions and we can't prevent it? @Highway of Life

Comment: this is output for 3339 number:
Lütfen bir sayı giriniz: 3339 thred2 3334 thred3 6667 thred1 1000 thred1 1001 thred3 6668 thred2 3335 thred3 6669 thred1 1002 thred2 3336 thred2 3337 thred1 1003 thred3 6670 thred1 1004 thred3 6671 thred2 3338 thred2 3339 2. Thread şifreyi buldu: 3339 thred1 1005 thred3 6672

Answer (score 0):

Each threads needs to check some kind of *sentinel* to determine wether it should continue running (or not).

There are more complex ways of doing this using semaphores or signals but this is simple, understandable and works for this use-case.

The 3 functions in the original question can be reduced to just one by passing appropriate parameters.

```
from threading import Thread, Event
from time import sleep

RANGES = [(1000, 3334), (3334, 6667), (6667, 10000)]
EVENT = Event()
THREADS = []

def func(number, r, _id):
    for i in range(*r):
        sleep(0.02)
        if EVENT.is_set():
            break
        print(_id, i)
        if number == i:
            EVENT.set()
            print(f"thred{_id}.. Thread şifreyi buldu: {i}")
            break

def main():
    number = int(input("Lütfen bir sayı giriniz: "))

    for i, r in enumerate(RANGES, 1):
        THREADS.append(Thread(target=func, args=(number, r, i)))
        THREADS[-1].start()

    for t in THREADS:
        t.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: thank you very much but there is only one problem "Thread 2 found password:" after printing other 2 more times working. Can we prevent this too?

Comment: Lütfen bir sayı giriniz: 
3339
thred2 3334
thred3 6667
thred1 1000
thred1 1001
thred3 6668
thred2 3335
thred3 6669
thred1 1002
thred2 3336
thred2 3337
thred1 1003
thred3 6670
thred1 1004
thred3 6671
thred2 3338
thred2 3339
2. Thread şifreyi buldu: 3339
thred1 1005
thred3 6672

Comment: @Fatih You cannot guarantee that will happen. However, if you test the Event immediately after the *sleep()* the chances are greater of the threads stopping when you want them to do so